# JavaFx silently fails on FXML binding errors

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

We are working on a JavaFx 2.2 Desktop Application.

The workflow is fine, creating FXML Files using the Scene Builder and attaching them into my controllers using the FXML annotation.

However it would be nice if JavaFx could give me some debugging information if the binding fails.

Example:
I have an annotated property

`// In MyController class
@FXML private Button addButton`

which gets bound to its counter part in FXML:

`<!-- In my FXML File --> 
<Button fx:id="addButton" text="Add" />`

If I mistype "addButton", the Button member field will keep on "null" but it would be easy for the FXMLLoader do detect such errors (unbound fx:id-Elements). Is there any possibility to implement or activate such checks?

At the moment we are using a long list of assertions.